# Create custom URL to trigger button

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

So i have a button on the footer of the website, that has the class ".subscrever" and that triggers a popup open on click.

http://salpoente.pt/

I can i make a custom URL to trigger that click? For example "http://salpoente.pt/#subscrever" . How do i make this custom URL trigger that button click to make the popup open? All i want is to have a custom link that i can use for the client to open the site and have the popup opened already.

Tried everything with jquery and didnt managed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a URL parameter, such as `http://salpoente.pt?subscrever=true`.

Then, you have to get the parameter when the page loads:

```
function getParam(param)
{
    var url= window.location.search.substring(1);
    var urlParams = url.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < urlParams.length; i++) 
    {
        var paramName = urlParams[i].split('=');
        if (paramName[0] == param) 
        {
            return paramName[1];
        }
    }
}​

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(getParam("subscrever") === true) {
        $("#subscrever").click()
        //Or just call the button's onclick function directly
    }
});
```

Comment: tried to add that to my custom javascript, didn't worked. the url doesn't open anything

Comment: @PedroFidalgo I notice that you said your button is of the *class* subscrever.  This code relies on it having the *id* subscrever. You need a way to isolate the specific button by giving it a unique id.  Otherwise, use your browser's inspector to see if the code is executing and getting the parameter correctly.

Comment: Its not a button. Its a href only. I gave the a href the class and id "subscrever". Still does not work. you can check the website to see the a href has the class and id

Comment: I know that if i put this onclick on a button it opens the modal. onclick="PUM.open(3454);

Comment: I just want to have a custom link triggering this

Comment: Looking at your site, it looks like you don't have jQuery (`$ is not a function`).  Try getting rid of the `$(document).ready` function (it's probably not really needed anyway, if you're calling your function directly) and have the param check run as the page loads.

Comment: I added this to the header, still nothing... function getParam(param)
{
    var url= window.location.search.substring(1);
    var urlParams = url.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < urlParams.length; i++) 
    {
        var paramName = urlParams[i].split('=');
        if (paramName[0] == param) 
        {
            return paramName[1];
        }
    }
}

function() {
    if(getParam("subscrever") === true) {
        PUM.open(3454);
        //Or just call the button's onclick function directly
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Don't think about it as the link clicking the button; the link opens the modal, and so does the button.

```
if ( window.location.hash === '#subscrever' ) openModal()
```